# Let $\dfrac{a}{b},\dfrac{c}{d}\in\Bbb{Q}$. Define what we mean by the product of two rationals and prove that the product is well-defined...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

...that is, if $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{a′}{b′}$ and $\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{c′}{d′}$, then $\dfrac{a}{b}\cdot\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{a′}{b′}\cdot\dfrac{c′}{d′}$.

I'm unsure of what this question means by "define the product of two rationals". Am I defining what happens when two rationals are multiplied? It seems explanatory, though I'm sure something is going over my head.

Furthermore, I understand that to be well-defined means to be associative, meaning the order of the rationals in this case should not alter the result. What I don't understand is the use of $a'$, $b'$, $c'$, and $d'$ here. Why take the derivative and how does that help me prove that the product is well-defined? Sorry if this is a simple question, I'm just unsure of how to apply the given information to a proof.

Comment: Think of $a, a'$ as $a_1, a_2$.  The use of the prime does not denote any derivative.  So you have eight variables: $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2, d_1, d_2$.

Comment: I have already shown you a MathJax tutorial. Please use it.

Comment: "I understand that to be well-defined means to be associative, meaning the order of the rationals in this case should not alter the result. "  That's not actually what well defined means.  Well, defined means if something can be represented in multiple ways it gives the same result.  For example if we defined $f(n)$ as $f(n) = a+b$ where $a\cdot b = n$, so for example $f(12) = 3+4=7$ because $3\cdot 4=12$ is *not* well-defined.  $12 = 2\cdot 6 = 1\cdot 12$ so $f(12)$ could equal $2+6=8$ or it could equal $1+12 =13$.  ... to be continued....

Comment: ... Another example.  Suppose I wanted to define $p \circ q$ as when $p = \frac ab$ and $q =\frac mn$ then $\frac ab \circ \frac mn = \frac {a+m}{b+n}$.  This is not well-defined because  $0.5\circ  0.75 = \frac 12 \circ \frac 34=\frac {1+3}{2+4}=\frac 46 = \frac 23$ but $0.5\circ  0.75 = \frac 5{10}\circ \frac {75}{100} = \frac {10+75}{10+100} = \frac {85}{110} = \frac {17}{22}$.

Comment: So you need to prove that if $\frac ab = \frac cd$ and if $\frac mn=\frac pq$ that $\frac ab \times \frac mn = \frac cd \times \frac pq$.... But before you do that you *do* have to define what $\frac ab\times \frac mn =?????$ is.

Answer (score 1):

You are required to prove that the multiplication formula for fractions is well-defined, i.e., does not depend on the representation of the fractions. As often an example here helps.

$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1\cdot 1}{2\cdot 3}=\frac{1}{6},
$$

but is the equation well-defined, if I write, say, $\frac{8}{16}$ for the first fraction and $\frac{3}{9}$ for the second one?

Comment: No problem :-) ${}$

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say: 
$$\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}$$
which is always verified.
For the hypothesis done $\left (\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a_1}{b_1}, \frac{c_1}{d_1}=\frac{c}{d}\right)$, we arrive at:
$$\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a_1}{b_1}\cdot\frac{c_1}{d_1}$$

Answer (score 0):

A rational number is defined by two integers.  So if $p = \frac ab$ where $a,b$ are integers and $q = \frac mn$ are integers than how *do* you define $p\cdot q$?

They are literally asking how you define that.

And I think you know the answer to that.

> If $p = \frac ab$ and $q = \frac mn$ then $p\cdot q$ can be defined as $\frac {am}{bn}$.

*BUT* is that well defined?  There are more then just *pair* of integers that can describe a rational.  $p$ can equal $\frac ab$ but it can also equal $\frac wv$ or $\frac {\omega}{\gamma}$ or an infinite number of pairs.  If $p= \frac ab = \frac wv$ and $q=\frac mn \frac zx$, and if you have defined what $p\cdot q$ means in terms of $(a,b)$ and $(m,n)$ how do you know the definition will hold for $(w,v)$ and $(z,w)$?

In other words

If $p = \frac ab = wv$ and $q=\frac mn = \frac zw$ and we define $\frac ab \cdot \frac mn$ as

> $\frac {am}{bn}$

How do we know that $\frac ab\cdot \frac mn = \frac wv\cdot \frac yz$?  That is:

> How do we know $\frac {am}{bn} = \frac {wy}{vz}$?